# How to add property from code to media type?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I use Umbraco 7.4.12 And I need to add property to media type dynamically from code and not from the UI.

What the best way to do this?

[image: Add property from UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do?

Below I am adding a textstring property to the default Image media type. I even tested it just now, and it's working :-)

There is an overload to the AddPropertyType method which allows you to add the property to a given tab/property group if needed.

```
protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        var contentTypeService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentTypeService;
        var dataTypeService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.DataTypeService;

        var mediaType = contentTypeService.GetMediaType(1032);

        if (mediaType != null && !mediaType.PropertyTypeExists("myNewPropertyAlias"))
        {
            var dataTypeDefinitions = dataTypeService.GetAllDataTypeDefinitions().ToArray();
            var textStringDataTypeDefinition = dataTypeDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "textstring");

            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new PropertyType(textStringDataTypeDefinition) { Name = "My New Property Name", Alias = "myNewPropertyAlias" });

            contentTypeService.Save(mediaType);
        }
    }
```